# How to update or change data in sql server through jsp code after valid login? Getting an exception occurred processing update data

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, jsp

I have written all my codes in jsp. I am using eclipse, tomcat server and sql server management studio. After login with registered user name and password. I am trying to change or update contact number & email id but it fails to do so. 
I am sharing my success.jsp code (which is about after successfully login and asks for to update contact and email fields) and update2.jsp code (which is about the functionality to update data into the same account through which I login.

1.success.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="update2.jsp">
<center>

  <h2>


<%
String a=session.getAttribute("username").toString();
out.println("Hello " +a);

%>


            <center>
            <table border="1" width="30%" cellpadding="5">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th colspan="2">Update Information Here</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Contact</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="contact" value="" /></td>

                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td>Email</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="" /></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Update" /></td>
                        <td><input type="reset" value="Reset" /></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            </center>

               </h2>
<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>
</center>

  </form>>

The date now is: <%= new java.util.Date() %>

</body>
</html>

2. update2.jsp

<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
      <%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
      <%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
    <%@page import="java.sql.*,java.io.*,java.text.*,java.util.*" %> 
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> 
<%@ page import= " java.sql.DriverManager"  %>
<%@page import= "java.sql.SQLException" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>



<%
String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
String email = request.getParameter("email");
String job= request.getParameter("job");
String place= request.getParameter("place");
String contact= request.getParameter("contact");

if(request.getParameter("submit") !=null)
{
Connection con = null;
PreparedStatement ps = null;

//String user1 = Integer.parseInt(uname);
try
{
    //Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
    Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;");
String sql="Update members2 set uname=?,pass=?,fname=?,lname=?,email=?, job=?,place=?,contact=? where uname=?,pass=?";
//String sqlEDIT="UPDATE members2(email,contact) VALUES(?,?)"
ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
ps.setString(1,user);
ps.setString(2,pwd);
ps.setString(3, fname);
ps.setString(4, lname);
ps.setString(5, email);
ps.setString(6, job);
ps.setString(7, place);
ps.setString(8, contact);
int i = ps.executeUpdate();
if(i > 0)
{
out.print("Record Updated Successfully");
}
else
{
out.print("There is a problem in updating Record.");
}
}
catch(SQLException sql)
{
request.setAttribute("error", sql);
out.println(sql);
}
}



%> 
</body>
</html>
```

**The error is as below:**

```
**HTTP Status 500** - An exception occurred processing JSP page /update2.jsp at line 42

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /update2.jsp at line 42

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /update2.jsp at line 42

    39:     Connection con1 = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;integratedSecurity=true;");
    40: String sql="Update members2 set uname=?,pass=?,fname=?,lname=?,email=?, job=?,place=?,contact=? where uname=?,pass=?";
    41: //String sqlEDIT="UPDATE members2(email,contact) VALUES(?,?)"
    42: ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    43: ps.setString(1,user);
    44: ps.setString(2,pwd);
    45: ps.setString(3, fname);


    Stacktrace:
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:575)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:477)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



    root cause 
    java.lang.NullPointerException
        org.apache.jsp.update2_jsp._jspService(update2_jsp.java:131)
        org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
        org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: I suggest you to follow MVC design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql string has 10 parameters:

```
String sql="Update members2 set uname=?,pass=?,fname=?,lname=?,email=?, job=?,place=?,contact=? where uname=?,pass=?";
```

but you are setting eight.